# How to use chain rule on it?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ oriented by $\vec n$. For a fixed number $\varepsilon\neq0$, let $F:M\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be a mapping such that $F(p)=p+\varepsilon\vec n(p)$ and denote $\overline{M}=F(M)$. Knowing $\vec{x}(u,v)$ a parametrization of $M$, so we know parametrization $\vec{y}(u,v)$ of $\overline{M}$ is $\vec{y}(u,v)$=$\vec{x}(u,v)+\varepsilon\vec{n}(\vec{x}(u,v))$.

> Now there is a question:Use E(of $\vec{x}(u,v)$)(by fist fundamental forms)to represent $\overline{E}$ of $\vec{y}(u,v)$.

I don't know how to use chain rule on it.

Thanks. Please help me.

Comment: There's nothing to do with chain rule. You just calculate.

Comment: My steps:$\overline{E}=\vec{y}_u\cdot\vec{y}_u=(\vec{x}_u+\varepsilon\vec{n}(\vec{x}_u))\cdot(\vec{x}_u+\varepsilon\vec{n}(\vec{x}_u))$.I don't know my steps have any problems or not,could somebody can teach me?Thanks.

Comment: Could someone can give me hint?Thanks.